# Problems with Selenium, especially with optimization

Tags: python, selenium

Guys I have a problem with efficiency in my code

I need to extract certain data from web page with land properties / apartments and later on alanyse them, but my code runs extremely slow, would You be so kind and help me?

PS I am new one to web scraping

```
driver.get('https://www.olx.pl/nieruchomosci/dzialki')


innerLayout = driver.find_element_by_id('innerLayout')
print(innerLayout)
container = innerLayout.find_element_by_id('body-container')
offer_wrap = container.find_elements_by_class_name("offer-wrapper")

for i in offer_wrap:
    link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body-container"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/h3/a')
    link.click()

    outerClass = driver.find_element_by_id('offerdescription')

    time.sleep(10)
#price of field

    parcel = outerClass.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="offerdescription"]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/span/strong')

    price= []

    for i in parcel:
        price.append(i.text)
    time.sleep(10)

#surface

    surface = outerClass.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="offerdescription"]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/span/strong')

    surf = []

    for j in surface:
        surf.append(j.text)

    time.sleep(10)
    driver.back()





print(price)
print(surf)
```

Comment: You have three `time.sleep(10)` statements in your loop, so each loop takes 30 seconds of waiting time. This could probably be sped up by using explicit waits. If you read the [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) you can find out how to.

Comment: Just adding to what @Beek is saying use better locators and `wait'`s  also, your main loop should not iterate the elements to avoid `StaleElementReferenceException`

Comment: Try to avoid so many `time.sleep`. It's better to use waits, but in your case, most probably you don't need it at all. You can add `time.sleep(1)` once per 100 loops to reduce chances of being banned by website. Also, I'm not 100% sure as didn't inspect this website, but check that you really need loops inside main loop. Looks like you just need to iterate over offers once (to collect prices and descriptions)

Answer (score 1):

Please avoid `time.sleep()`. This is kind of static wait which will still wait even if your element is visible and can do interaction.

Based on your code, I could not find better situation like why you are using 10 seconds sleep at some point.

This is one of example where you can replace your time.sleep wtih explicit wait :

```
 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "Your element Xpath here"))
    )
```

Also your most of xpaths are absolute, Please use relative xpaths which will make your script more stable.

I have some good xpath for you here :

```
Your xpath : //*[@id="body-container"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/h3/a
Better xpath : (//table[@summary='Ogłoszenie']//tr//td//h3/a)[1]


Your xpath : //*[@id="offerdescription"]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/span/strong
Better xpath : (//span[@class='offer-details__name'])[3]


Your xpath : //*[@id="offerdescription"]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/span/strong
Better xpath : (//span[contains(@class,'name')])[4]
```

Please remember that optimization of xpath may not affect much on execution speed of your script but it will definitely make script stable.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your usage of `time.sleep()`, but you better avoid it. Try using `WebDriverWait`. You can find it [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)